What should I do if my question is based on an incorrect assumption but has an answer?
Recently, I asked a question, and someone provided an answer. After further study, I realized that my question was based on an incorrect interpretation of a definition, which made both my question and the answer incorrect (though the answer would be correct if my assumption were valid).
I'm now unsure how to handle this situation. Should I edit my question to explain why it’s incorrect, leave a comment on the answer, or delete my question altogether? What’s the best course of action to ensure clarity for others who may read this question and answer in the future?

Could you link to the problem in question?  On its face, I'd say "if the question made sense as it was written and if the answer correctly resolved the written question, then I'd leave it up and post a new question asking what you intended to ask the first time.  Write a comment to the old answer pointing that user to the new question, should they want to take a shot, and edit the old post to link to the revised question."  But of course I don't know if that describes your situation or not.

Good question here. Thanks for seeking advice on proper procedure.

Once a question has been answered, do not edit that question in such a way as to invalidate that answer.

This probably happens sometimes in literature as well.  There could be a false theorem lurking around.
